# NuGet package update error for EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

Tags: c#, entity-framework, nuget, visual-studio-2017

I recently updated an old c# UWP project of mine that I haven't worked on since December/January. So I decided to open it and update all packaged via `nuget`.

I'm running `VS2017 v15.3.1` and `nuget v4.3.0`.

So I updated all packages via nuget, but having trouble updating the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools`:

> Restoring packages for D:\Programming\C#\Projekts VS2017\myUWPproject\myUWPproject\myUWPproject.csproj...
>     GET https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory/index.json
>     OK https://api.nuget.org/v3-flatcontainer/microsoft.identitymodel.clients.activedirectory/index.json 462ms
>   Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication 1.0.10 does not provide an inclusive lower bound for dependency Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (> 2.22.0 && < 3.0.0). An approximate best match of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.22.302111727 was resolved.
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-arm. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-arm-aot. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x64. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x64-aot. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x86. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393) / win10-x86-aot. Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0)
>   Package restore failed. Rolling back package changes for 'myUWPproject'.
>   Time Elapsed: 00:00:02.1287297
>   ========== Finished ==========

So I removed it from the project and just in case I also removed the folder `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\NuGetPackages\Tools` as well, but with no luck. When trying to reinstall it, I get above output.

First I thought it might be because of

```
Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication 1.0.10 does not provide an inclusive lower bound for dependency Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory (> 2.22.0 && < 3.0.0). An approximate best match of Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory 2.22.302111727 was resolved.
```

so after removing it. It still gave the same of the message (without the `Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication` part), so I reinstalled it again.

I also tried to set Minimum and Target Version to the Creators Update in hope of solving the `uap10.0.14393` issue, but with no luck, so I set the Minimum Version back to 14393 (Anniversary Update).

Can someone help me into the right direction? I'm not sure, what else I could try.

If it is any help, the rest of the installed packages are:

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite v2.0.0
Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform v5.4.0
Microsoft.OneDriveSDK v2.0.7
Microsoft.OneDriveSDK.Authentication v1.0.10
Win2D.uwp v1.21.0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> So I updated all packages via nuget, but having trouble updating the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools

There is a key point you need to pay attention. **Microsoft**, the author of package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` **has released a new version 2.0** on August 12, 2017 (8/12/2017) (several days ago), **which supports: .netstandard2.0**.

[image]

However, the SDK `10.0.14393` and `10.0.15063` are not been updated to compatible with that package with .netstandard2.0. So if you now install the package, which supports: .netstandard2.0. to the UWP project, you will get below error:

> Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 is not compatible with uap10.0.14393 (UAP,Version=v10.0.14393). Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools 2.0.0 supports: netstandard2.0 (.NETStandard,Version=v2.0) Package

To resolve this issue, please please use the package `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` with the **version 1.1.1 instead of 2.0.0**.

Update: There is a [release note for .netstandard 2.0](https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24): "UWP is work in progress and will ship later this year."

Comment: Ah I didn't know about the `.netstandard2.0` thing. So I'll use `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools` v1.1.1 until the new SDK is out (somewhere in the end of this year I presume). Thank you very much, I got a real headache about this :D

Comment: @user3079834, yes, https://github.com/dotnet/announcements/issues/24 “UWP is work in progress and will ship later this year”